# JDBC connection to Amazon Kinesis

Tags: java, jdbc, amazon-kinesis

> Hi All,
>
> Can one establish a JDBC connection to Amazon Kinesis ? , if so can
>   you please provide the jdbc jar and connection URL.If JDBC is not a
>   possibility then what all ways can one establish connectivity with
>   Amazon Kinesis on a remote machine from local system.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem?

Comment: @Manoj Kumar Dhakd Basically I want to know the pros and cons of using AWS SDK vs using KPL, and which is better . Given that I am only interested in putting records to kinesis stream (once it is put one does not care of how it is being read) , so the scenario is only being able to write to kinesis data streams faster.